# Calling a function from another component with redux

Tags: redux

Trying to toggle open a modal from another component with redux. Almost there but not really sure how to finish it up - been looking around for a clear answer!

On the HomeScreen component (the main component), to activate the openModal method on the AddCircleModal component, causing the Modal to open.

**The Modal - AddCircleModal:** Using redux, I can successfully close the modal if I open it manually in the code

```
class AddCircleModal extends React.Component {
    state = {
        top: new Animated.Value(screenHeight),
        modalVisible: false
    }

    // componentDidMount() {
    //         this.openModal()
    //     }

    openModal = () => {
        Animated.spring(this.state.top, {
            toValue: 174
        }).start()
        this.setState({modalVisible: true})
    }

    closeModal = () => {
        Animated.spring(this.state.top, {
            toValue: screenHeight
        }).start()
        this.setState({modalVisible: false})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
             transparent={true}
             visible={this.state.modalVisible}
             >
                <AnimatedContainer style={{ top: this.state.top, }}>
                    <Header />
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={this.closeModal}
                        style={{ position: "absolute", top: 120, left: "50%", marginLeft: -22, zIndex: 1 }}
                    >
                        <CloseView style={{ elevation: 10 }}>
                            <FeatherIcon name="plus" size={24} />
                        </CloseView>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Body />
                </AnimatedContainer>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { action: state.action }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        closeModal: () =>
            dispatch({
                type: "CLOSE_MODAL"
            })
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddCircleModal)
```

**HomeScreen:** The other component that I want to toggle from

```
//redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import styles from './Styles'

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  toggleOpenCircleModal = () => {
      // this.openModal() - what do I do with this to call the openModal function in the modal component?
      console.log('owwwww weeeee')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <HomeHeader openModal={this.toggleOpenCircleModal}/> - this method is because I'm calling toggleOpenCircleModal from a button in the header of the home screen. It works as it outputs the 'owwwww weeeee' string to the console.
        
      <SafeAreaView style={{ width: '100%', flex: 1}} />
    
           <AddCircleModal />

      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { action: state.action }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        openModal: () =>
            dispatch({
                type: "OPEN_MODAL"
            })
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen)
```

**modalToggle:** The reducer

```
const initialState = {
    action: ""
}

const modalToggle = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "OPEN_MODAL":
            return { ...state, action: "openModal" }
        case "CLOSE_MODAL":
            return { ...state, action: "closeModal" }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default modalToggle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your components are not using redux store properly.

When you use `mapStateToProps`, you can access every redux store reducer. You can access every prop in them and these will be sent via `props` in your connected component. For instance:

```
//redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import styles from './Styles'

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  toggleOpenCircleModal = () => {
      if(this.props.action === 'openModal') {
         this.props.openModal();
      } else {
         this.props.closeModal();
      }
  }


  render() {
    const { action } = this.props; // this.props.action is coming from Redux Store
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
         {action} // this will be 'openModal'
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { action: state.action } // this will be available in HomeScreen as props.action
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        openModal: () =>
            dispatch({
                type: "OPEN_MODAL"
            })
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen)
```

You can read more on https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate.

The same goes for `mapDispatchToProps`. In your case, `openModal` will be available in `props.openModal` in your `HomeScreen` component. You can read more on https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Based on this, in your `AddCircleModal` component, you should be using `props.action` to evaluate if the modal should be visible. (`props.action === 'openModal'`).

If you want to open or close your modal, you'll just need to call the `openModal` or `closeModal` dispatch call in your component. In `HomeScreen` component, in your function `toggleOpenCircleModal`, you will call `openModal()` or `closeModal()` depending on `props.action === 'openModal'`.

Lastly, you should be using just a boolean value to check for the modal visibility, instead of a string, if that's the only purpose for your reducer.

```
const initialState = false;

const modalToggle = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "OPEN_MODAL":
            return true;
        case "CLOSE_MODAL":
            return false;
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default modalToggle
```

Comment: Understand the second half of your answer but not sure I get the logic of the first. Why can't I have the mapDispatchToProps as I have it now and then just call that dispatch action by 'this.props.action'?

Comment: @JamesStirrat in `AddCircleModal` component, you are not using `this.props.action`. The first code snippet, I removed some code in sake of simplicity. I'll edit and add the `mapDispatchToProps`

Comment: @JamesStirrat I've edited my answer showing the code. The *actions* you dispatch, are the ones you have in `mapDispatchToProps`. `this.props.action` is a value from the store, that comes from `mapStateToProps`, from `modalToggle` reducer. Redux has this concept of one-way data flow https://redux.js.org/basics/data-flow. If you need to change something in your store, you do it by dispatching actions. Then, in your connected components, you consume from the redux store and expose those values as props for the unconnected component.

Comment: Ok I'm getting you! Although it seems now in my code (following what you have said), there is actually no dispatch happening in the console. I'll check my redux set up

Comment: Awesome! Make a follow up if you are still having issues

Comment: Got it! Answer was useful in helping me understand what was going on apart from ```{action} // this will be 'openModal' ```, which was still confusing (I guessed it meant that you would call props.openModal onPress). Thanks for the help!